# Embedding iframes and documents in flash apps

Tags: flash, apache-flex, iframe

I'm looking for possibility to show documents (docx, pdf,...) in my flassh apps. Is it possible? The other question is whether it's possible to embed iframe into flash app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can float an iframe over the top if it is a swf. If you do a web search, you will probably find this more in connection with Flex than pure Flash.

If this is an AIR file, you can load it in with an HTMLLoader.